# How does tension apply a downward force parallel to mg?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I was stuck on part "e" and my teacher told me that due to N1L the normal force is equal to the downwards force. So I thought that the downwards force would be the sum of the weight of the system which is the normal force. However he said that it is actually the weight of the stand  and pulley plus tension1 and tension2. My question is how and why on earth does the tension contribute to the downwards force. It is a internal force so it is not even act on the system.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define the system.  If the system is the pulley and stand, then tension is an external downward force, and the mass of the system is the mass of the pulley plus the mass of the stand.

If the system is the pulley, stand, and masses, then tension is an internal force, as you say.   In that case the mass of the system is the mass of the pulley plus the mass of the stand plus the masses of the two hanging weights.

Answer (score 0):

If you make FBD of pulley you will find that tension1 and tension2 acts downwards on it
You can understand it easily if you consider that since the weight of the 2 loads are supported by pulley hence by newtons third law of motion pulley will experience equal and downwards force due to blocks

Comment: The pulley is supporting the tensions in the string. These are not necessarily equal to the weights of the two masses, if they are accelerating.

Comment: Yes don't know why I wrote that

Answer (score 0):

According to your question why and how tension contributes to the downward force?? Yes the answer is that hence in a system like pulley a tension is force that must be to balance with weight mg in order a body to undergo acceleration! But there some internal force like friction force your question don't specify!!